# Accessing a value in a deciles data structure

Tags: pandas, series

I do this

```
dec = df.groupby(pd.qcut(df.num,10)).mean() 
dec.unstack=1
dnum  = dec['num'] 
dnum
```

This yields a structure with an untitled column:

```
num
(-0.001, 4.0]       1.807960
(4.0, 9.0]          7.008487
(9.0, 17.0]        13.341535
(17.0, 26.0]       21.971478
(26.0, 36.0]       31.369977
(36.0, 48.0]       42.212227
(48.0, 63.0]       55.994531
(63.0, 77.0]       70.219310
(77.0, 107.0]      90.825823
(107.0, 307.0]    143.040535
Name: num, dtype: float64
```

How to access only the second column so that I get a series

```
1.807960, 7.008487, etc. ?
```

Comment: That's a series with an index. Just do `dnum.values`?

Comment: *How to access only the second column so that I get a series* you out put is series